# JQuery Mobile TypeError: t.split is not a function

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I was working on a website, but for some reason JQuery Mobile just refuses to work.
Now I've made a simple demo page using code literally copied from the JQuery Mobile example, here it is:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html> 
   <html> 
    <head> 
        <title>My Page</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page" id="1">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>My Title</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">   
        <p>Hello world</p>      
        <a href='#2' data-transition='slide'>2</a>
    </div><!-- /content -->

</div><!-- /page -->


<div data-role="page" id="2">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>My Title</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">   
        <p>Hello world2</p>     
        <a href='#1' data-transition='slide'>1</a>
    </div><!-- /content -->

</div><!-- /page -->

</body>
</html>
```

This for some reason doesn't work, and returns me an error saying "TypeError: t.split is not a function". Would anyone know what's going wrong?

Comment: Have you checked to ensure the CDN locations are actually returning data?

Comment: @ShaunHare They do link to the scripts, and I got it from the official JQuery Mobile example so I'd imagine it's up to date.

Comment: @Omar I won't, as it is not the same question. One is about JQuery Mobile not working for my specific website. This one is about it not working in general. If people actually cared to help solve questions instead of asnwer twice and then just leave we would have 0 open questions instead of 2. (I also specifically stated I would ignore the issue with the website and move on).

Comment: **t.split is not a function** for both questions. Where are the differences between your questions?

Comment: @Omar As I said, even though the error message is the same, it's still both different websites and most likely caused by different problems. Instead of complaining about my ignored question you could try to help? Or should we delete every question that's dealing with a 404 error, because they're the "the same"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating the version of jQuery (1.9.2) and jQuery Mobile (1.3.1) framework you are using.

Also, I tried in fiddle and your code worked for me.

Okay got it.

You have added only numbers in id, I changed them to page1 and page2:

```
<div data-role="header">
    <h1>My Title</h1>
</div><!-- /header -->

<div data-role="content">   
    <p>Hello world</p>      
    <a href='#page2' data-transition='slide'>2</a>
</div><!-- /content -->
```

```
<div data-role="header">
    <h1>My Title</h1>
</div><!-- /header -->

<div data-role="content">   
    <p>Hello world2</p>     
    <a href='#page1' data-transition='slide'>1</a>
</div><!-- /content -->
```

Now it works.

Comment: I just tried it in Fiddle and couldn't get it to work... I have never been this confused. I've tried it with the newer version of both JQuery and JQuery Mobile and it's returning the exact same errors.

Comment: It Works! Thanks dude! I'm guessing just numbers won't be enough for an ID :P

Comment: @Parrotmaster could **you** make a fiddle for ur problem? I think it will make us understand where you are making this error.

Comment: @Parrotmaster: Yes and also as a best practice never use only numbers use something meaningful for id's its very important, i personally use "page<module name>".

Comment: @hungerpain The problem is that the code contains some info that I'm not allowed to share :/ Annoying I know.